# MFC Get Folders

Tags: c++, mfc, directory

Hey how do I in MFC get names of all folders? Any examples or which classes should I look into? Any hints will be really appreciated. All I saw is the CFile, which as far as I have seen (though very very little) doesn't looks like it has the ability to do what I want. So please direct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into [CFileFind](http://www.ddj.com/windows/184416436)

There is an [old article in DDJ](http://www.ddj.com/windows/184416436) on how to implement a recursive search using `CFileFind`.

Comment: Pay close attention to the IsDirectory member function.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search revealed an nice example in: [Listing the Files in a Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28VS.85%29.aspx)

It uses [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418(VS.85).aspx), [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428(VS.85).aspx), and [FindClose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364413(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: This is the Windows API way to do it, not MFC.

Answer (score 1):

Look for FindFirstFile in the MFC documentation